# Why the jQuery is taking the original DOM element classes even though I changed them with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```js
$(".drop-down-arrow-open i").click(function(){
 console.log("click function for .drop-down-arrow-open is applied even when it is closed");
 let thisParent = $(this).closest(".projects-container").find(".needed-while-hiding");
 thisParent.hide();

 $(this).closest(".drop-down-arrow-open").removeClass("drop-down-arrow-open").addClass("drop-down-arrow-closed");
 $(this).removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-right");
});

$(".drop-down-arrow-closed i").click(function(){
  console.log("This is never applied");
 let thisParent = $(this).closest(".projects-container").find(".needed-while-hiding");
 thisParent.show();

 $(this).closest(".drop-down-arrow-closed").removeClass("drop-down-arrow-closed").addClass("drop-down-arrow-open");
 $(this).removeClass("fa-chevron-right").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
});
```

```css
span.drop-down-arrow-open, span.drop-down-arrow-closed{
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #636b6f;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="projects-container">
 <h1>Project Name<span class="drop-down-arrow-open"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></span></h1>
 <div class="needed-while-hiding">
  <p class="description-background full-width adjust-properties">Description</p>
  <div class="a-little-inside">
   <ul class="list-without-bullets">
    <li><span>Duration: </span><span>Some Duration</span></li>
    <li><span>Roles: </span><span>Some Role related to development</span></li>
    <li><span>Controller: </span><span>Pipeline</span></li>
    <li><span>Official Website: </span><a href="javascript:void(0)">Random Link</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

In the above code, I am trying to open and close a drop down. I have two click functions, one for each open and close class. By default, the buttons have open class. At first, all drop downs are open by default, but when the `fa-chevron-down` is clicked, the close class is added and open is removed from the element using jQuery.

I have seen that in the web inspector, this logic works fine, but when the closed class is appended in the DOM, the click function of that class is never applied, instead the click function for open keeps on applying.

Am I missing something here. Please help me solve this issue. I am trying to make a portfolio, and I am stuck at this issue.

**Note :** By `open` class I mean, `.drop-down-arrow-open` and by `close` class I mean, `.drop-down-arrow-closed`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess all the answers here are perfect solution to my query, for anyone having the same trouble, please go through all of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the class "drop-down-arrow-closed" is not found on the time of DOM creation. To make sure always use

```
$('body').on('event', 'element', funciton)
```

So it will bind the event for the element which is already created or created later

```js
$('body').on('click',".drop-down-arrow-open i",function(){
 
 let thisParent = $(this).closest(".projects-container").find(".needed-while-hiding");
 thisParent.hide();

 $(this).closest(".drop-down-arrow-open").removeClass("drop-down-arrow-open").addClass("drop-down-arrow-closed");
 $(this).removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-right");
});

$('body').on('click',".drop-down-arrow-closed i",function(){
  console.log("This is never applied");
 let thisParent = $(this).closest(".projects-container").find(".needed-while-hiding");
 thisParent.show();

 $(this).closest(".drop-down-arrow-closed").removeClass("drop-down-arrow-closed").addClass("drop-down-arrow-open");
 $(this).removeClass("fa-chevron-right").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
});
```

```css
span.drop-down-arrow-open, span.drop-down-arrow-closed{
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #636b6f;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="projects-container">
 <h1>Project Name<span class="drop-down-arrow-open"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></span></h1>
 <div class="needed-while-hiding">
  <p class="description-background full-width adjust-properties">Description</p>
  <div class="a-little-inside">
   <ul class="list-without-bullets">
    <li><span>Duration: </span><span>Some Duration</span></li>
    <li><span>Roles: </span><span>Some Role related to development</span></li>
    <li><span>Controller: </span><span>Pipeline</span></li>
    <li><span>Official Website: </span><a href="javascript:void(0)">Random Link</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to, but most of the solutions are too good and working out for me, let me try and find the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `$(selector)` binds the click handler at the time it is called. So you're binding the closing handler on the element, and not binding the opening handler anywhere, as such elements don't exist when running the code.

To overcome this, you could remove the callback within the callback itself, while also adding the alternate callback.

```
$el = $(".drop-down-arrow-open i")
var closeFn = function() {
    let thisParent = $el.closest(".projects-container").find(".needed-while-hiding");
    thisParent.hide();

    $el.closest(".drop-down-arrow-open").removeClass("drop-down-arrow-open").addClass("drop-down-arrow-closed");
    $el.removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-right");
    $el.off("click");
    $el.click(openFn);
});


var openFn = function(){
    let thisParent = $el.closest(".projects-container").find(".needed-while-hiding");
    thisParent.show();

    $el.closest(".drop-down-arrow-closed").removeClass("drop-down-arrow-closed").addClass("drop-down-arrow-open");
    $el.removeClass("fa-chevron-right").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
    $el.off("click");
    $el.click(closeFn);
});

$el.click(closeFn);
```

Comment: but I read somewhere, its not a good programming practice to nest another event listener in one.

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't nest them like I've done in this simplified example, but rather by naming them and using an approach similar to the [one by Fabio Tibaldi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52113398/2494631).

Comment: Okay your solution is helpful, but coding standards are important to me currently, because I am trying learn a new technology with this portfolio (Laravel), and it wont be nice if I will be lost in my own code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Code_Ninja see the updated code for a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1):

As @vijoc said the problem is that when you bind the events to the elements.
As a possible solution you can re-bind the correct event every time it has to change the click function.
Code

```
        $(function(){
           bindOpen($(".open"));
           bindClose($(".closed"));
        });

        function bindOpen(element){
           $(element).unbind("click").bind("click",function(){
               //your open stuff here
               console.log("open");
               bindClose(element);
           })
        }

        function bindClose(element){ 
           $(element).unbind("click").bind("click",function(){
               //your open stuff here
               console.log("close");
               bindOpen(element);
           })
        }
```

Comment: I wrote it quite in a hurry sorry. Do you see any error in console?

Comment: Yes it worked, that a lot for this solution, and also try referring to the one suggested by @balakrishnan. Looks like I missed a few things from your solution earlier.

Comment: Ok, to be sure I just added the "unbind" method so you are noew sure to completely override the old binding.

Answer (score 1):

Really, the click handler is bound to a known `DOMElement` matching the specified selector during runtime and when the selector changes you need to take care to update your selectors.

A workaround for this is to use the [`JQuery.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method to set a listener on a common parent `DOMElement` and filter through with another selector. An example for this using your use case is.

```
$(".parent-container").on("click", ".drop-down-arrow-open i", function() {
    ...
})
```

However, judging by your intent to reveal project details when the arrow icon is clicked and hide it when it is clicked again I find implementing it this way to be more readable by adding another class `drop-down-arrow` to target the arrow with.

```js
function toggleProjectDetails() {
   const $this = $(this)

   $this
    .closest(".projects-container")
    .find(".needed-while-hiding")
    .toggle();

  $this
    .toggleClass("drop-down-arrow-open drop-down-arrow-closed")

  $this.find('i')
  .toggleClass("fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-right")
}

$(".drop-down-arrow").on('click', toggleProjectDetails);
```

```css
span.drop-down-arrow-open,
span.drop-down-arrow-closed {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #636b6f;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="projects-container">
  <h1>Project Name<span class="drop-down-arrow drop-down-arrow-open"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></span></h1>
  <div class="needed-while-hiding">
    <p class="description-background full-width adjust-properties">Description</p>
    <div class="a-little-inside">
      <ul class="list-without-bullets">
        <li><span>Duration: </span><span>Some Duration</span></li>
        <li><span>Roles: </span><span>Some Role related to development</span></li>
        <li><span>Controller: </span><span>Pipeline</span></li>
        <li><span>Official Website: </span><a href="javascript:void(0)">Random Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```